# Remote port forwarding with ssh keys

Tags: ssh, localhost, port

I'm trying to access localhost:6006 on my remote ubuntu machine using public keys, and put it on my localhost:6006.

The command is something similar to:

`ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:6006:127.0.0.1:6006 ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XXX`

but I keep getting public key denied (but I can access the computer with my keys via normal ssh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify your private key with option -i.

```
ssh -i [path_of_your_private_key] -N -L 127.0.0.1:6006:127.0.0.1:6006 ubuntu@XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Comment: For those curious, to detach the process and have it run in the background add a `-f` so in a row the three commands are `-f -N -L`